# Alternative to SIP, voice communication in Android

Tags: java, android, communication, sip

Is it exists any alternative to SIP protocol? I want implement voice & video chat option in my application. I don't want use SIP, because I need only simple communication without call for landlines etc. It seems to me, it maybe doing with sockets, and audio records, but I'm not sure. I care about the fact that many people (for example 1000) could simultaneously carry on a conversation. Is it possible on regular server? Is it at all possible without a server?

Best regards.

Comment: This is a relatively standard application for SIP and Asterisk.  I suggest you research it better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Karl. I will apply to your council.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SIP protocol only deals with letting two communication partners find each other and negotiate audio/video capabilities. Once the communication partners know how to find each other, other protocols (like RTP) take over for the actual audio/video transfer.

So, if instances of your application can already reach each other, you can use those existing communication facilities to negotiate audio/video capabilities and establish a communication channel for the audio/video transfer.
If instances of your application can't reach each other, then you need to implement SIP or roll your own variant of it.

---

One of the ideas behind SIP is that, once communication has been established, the server does not have to remain in the communication path. This allows for a relatively lightweight server to serve a large number of calls.